# Angular2 Pipe - How can I do a basic string filter on a list of items?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Angular2 Pipe - How can I do a basic string filter on a list of items?

All I want to do is have an input text search box and enter a bit of text that filters the list of items in my ngFor.

I have no idea of how to do my own pipe.

Can someone show me how with the correct imports?

This used to be so simple in angular 1.x.

I'm using angular 2, typescript and html.

**Here is an example of my current html markup:**

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="search" />

  <tr *ngFor="#item of (jobs | search)"> 
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in pipe for this scenario so you might just have to build your own.

Comment: You can check the built-in pipes here, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=pipe

Comment: I need more help with this.

I only want to do a simple pipe

Comment: the documentation has a simple example. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Pipe-var.html

Comment: I've implemented that example and I get a typescript compiler error: "has no exported member pipe" ?

Comment: you should probably add an export keyword to the class definition, so other files can see it. **export class Lowercase**

Comment: hhttp://plnkr.co/edit/rLa1EcZC8uKw6MA2EXld?p=previewere's a working example.

Comment: That fixed the typescript compiler errors. So I know have a basic pipe. But how do I get it to filter my list as I type into the input box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99703/discussion-between-angularm-and-toskv).

Comment: Just got it working. thanks for the link above toskv

Comment: well... just in case I made a working plunkr of that too.. http://plnkr.co/edit/rLa1EcZC8uKw6MA2EXld?p=preview

Comment: Thanks toskv. Make an answer and il tick it so you get the points

Comment: it's fine the question is already set as duplicate. :)